# Wordpress URL question

Tags: posts, pages, urls, google

I have a web page that I created and in doing a google search for the company and my name a weird page came up. For private reasons I will not reveal the company name so I will use a fictitious company name. The URL that I found that came up was www.abc-tech.com/author/john and when I go to the URL the page shows up as a broken home screen with my name in the H1 saying ALL POSTS BY JOHN SMITH. I have no idea where this page is or how it is being created. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are your user information, [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-change-author-url-slug-and-base-in-wordpress/) can be helpful for you to change/update author slug.

There is no Author Template on your theme, have to create author template, https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Is there a way I can make that page not visible? I have an author page.

Comment: yes, this can be helpful for you http://smallbusiness.chron.com/hide-author-profile-wordpress-blog-52251.html

if this will be hard for you, you can try this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-author-pages/ (Note: I have not used myself this plugin before)

Comment: @sizemattic: You can just copy the url which you don't want to show on Google and copy the same in robot.txt file Please refer link for [more info](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)